# Nginx subdomains not functioning properly

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I'm trying to set up a subdomain on my digital ocean instance, and from what I can tell everything in both my domain's zone file and my site's Nginx configuration are correct - is there anything obvious that I'm doing wrong here?

The main domain functions as it should - it shows nothing, as I haven't configured the site files yet. The subdomain always forwards to another domain that I have hosted on the same DO instance.

DNS Zone:

```
$ORIGIN smsteammenus.com.
$TTL 1800
smsteammenus.com. IN SOA ns1.digitalocean.com. hostmaster.smsteammenus.com. 1452088962 10800 3600 604800 1800
smsteammenus.com. 1800 IN NS ns1.digitalocean.com.
smsteammenus.com. 1800 IN NS ns2.digitalocean.com.
smsteammenus.com. 1800 IN NS ns3.digitalocean.com.
smsteammenus.com. 1800 IN A **IP address**
www.smsteammenus.com. 1800 IN CNAME smsteammenus.com.
*.smsteammenus.com. 1800 IN CNAME smsteammenus.com.
staging.smsteammenus.com. 1800 IN A **the same IP address as above**
*.staging.smsteammenus.com. 1800 IN CNAME staging.smsteammenus.com.
```

Subdomain Nginx config:

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/smsteammenus.com/staging;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name staging.smsteammenus.com;

    location / {
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
     }
}
```

Main domain Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/smsteammenus.com/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name smsteammenus.com www.smsteammenus.com;

    location / {
        # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
           try_files $uri =404;
           fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
           fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
           fastcgi_index index.php;
           include fastcgi_params;
     }
}
```

I've compared to similar questions on ServerFault to no avail, and have triple checked that I've gone through all the proper steps (linking to sites-enabled, restarting nginx, etc.), but can't get this to work.

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Answer (score 1):

Played around with this in the meantime.

First, I created a completely separate directory for the subdomain, rather than trying to run both domains out of the same directory. Then, I copied the contents of the second Nginx configuration file into the main domain's Nginx configuration, modified what directories the domain needed to look at, and everything worked.